# HELM upgrade/install issue with azure pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I am trying to create a new namespace and install release name in azure pipelines, but my pipelines are getting timed-out after an hour.

Here's the code:

```yaml
- task: HelmDeploy@0 
  displayName: Dry run for upgrade 
  inputs: 
    connectionType: $(connectionType) 
    azureSubscription: $(azureServiceConnection) 
    azureResourceGroup: $(azureResourceGroup) 
    kubernetesCluster: $(kubernetesCluster) 
    namespace: '$(namespace)' 
    command: 'upgrade' 
    chartType: 'Name' 
    chartName: $(chartName) 
    releaseName: $(releaseName) 
    valueFile: $(valueFile) 
    install: true 
    waitForExecution: true 
    arguments: '--timeout 1h0m0s --create-namespace --install'
```

Can someone help with this case?

Answer (score 0):

The answer (which took me about a day of reading the docs to work out as I had the same issue) is simply that your HelmDeploy task requires internal Admin RBAC permissions.

The absolute easiest way to fix your code is to add `useClusterAdmin: true` to your `HelmDeploy@0` task e.g. add the last line:

```yaml
- task: HelmDeploy@0 
  displayName: Dry run for upgrade 
  inputs: 
    connectionType: $(connectionType) 
    azureSubscription: $(azureServiceConnection) 
    azureResourceGroup: $(azureResourceGroup) 
    kubernetesCluster: $(kubernetesCluster)
    namespace: '$(namespace)' 
    command: 'upgrade' 
    chartType: 'Name' 
    chartName: $(chartName) 
    releaseName: $(releaseName) 
    valueFile: $(valueFile) 
    install: true 
    waitForExecution: true 
    arguments: '--timeout 1h0m0s --create-namespace --install'
    useClusterAdmin: true
```

For clarity, this will bypass your cluster's RBAC permissions. If you wanted something more granular, then referring to [this dicussion](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/15802), you'd have to not use the dedicated HelmDeploy task, and use `AzureCLI@2` with `helm upgrade ...`.